# Dart Compress Uint8List Image

Tags: dart, compression, uint8list

How do I compress a Uint8List image? The purpose to to get a smaller size (length in bytes). I'm trying to avoid converting the Uint8List to File before compression.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind to use packages for it, you can use: [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)

Comment: I've tried this package but it doesn't take in a Uint8List, it only takes in file type. I resolved the issue by converting to file, compressing the file then converting back to Uint8List. Seems there's no shortcut to do this.

Comment: did you find any other solution..I also have the same issue and want to avoid the conversion of Uint8List to image before compression....

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
File imageFile = File.fromRawPath(uint8List);
var compressedImage = await testCompressFile(imageFile);

// compress file and get Uint8List
  Future<Uint8List?> testCompressFile(File file) async {
    Uint8List? result;
    try {
      result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(
        file.absolute.path,
        minWidth: 500,
        minHeight: 500,
        quality: 94,
      );
      print(file.lengthSync());
      print(result?.length);
    } on UnsupportedError catch (e) {
      print(e);

    }
    return result;
```

Comment: Can you clarify which package you are using?

Comment: used this one : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress , let me know if you have a problem with flutter web

Answer (score 0):

I also used https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress this package to compress my Uint8List image.

Here is my code for your reference. The flow is as follows:

1. Users pick an image by using the file picker that I've set to only able to pick `.png` or `.jpg` files.
2. I will get the file bytes and then compress it.

Based on the images that I've used for testing, it can reduce the byte length to almost half of the original size.

```
OutlinedButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                          type: FileType.custom,
                          allowedExtensions: ["jpg", "png"],
                          onFileLoading: (pickerStatus) {
                            if (pickerStatus == FilePickerStatus.done) {
                              setState(() {
                                _showFilePickerMessage = true;
                              });
                            }
                          },
                        ); // The code to pick the file

                        if (result != null) {
                          _fileName = result.files.first.name;

                          final fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes; // Get the bytes to be compressed here
                          if (fileBytes != null) {
                            final compressedBytes = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(
                              fileBytes,
                              format: CompressFormat.jpeg,
                            ); // Use this method to compress the image
                            Logger().d(compressedBytes.lengthInBytes / (1024 * 1024));
                            _base64EncodedDiagram = base64Encode(compressedBytes);
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.cloud_upload),
                      label: const Text('Upload diagram'),
                    ),
```